# Javascript selectors how to only get first ranking a refs

Tags: javascript, select, element

Hi there I'm fiarly new to coding. and doing some javascipt layouting. but I need to make some variables. and don't know how. I want to make a dropdown menu. for this site. [bertconinx.com](http://bertconinx.com) now in order to do the thing I want to do I need to be albe to select a href without having to change any html. let the browser go to the link and then execute some javascript so what I need to do is find a way how to select the specific a href. I need to select the head menu intem without selecting any submen Items. because they should be dropdowns on a clickevent.
I got as far as this..

```
a href="http://bertconinx.com/category/portrets/">Portrets</a 

a href="http://bertconinx.com/category/weddings/">Weddings</a>
```

should load first and then should dropdown his submenu clickevents.

but slecting the a href seems trick I've tried.

```
var MenuEvent = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item").getElementsByTagName("a");
```

But it does not work.

Any Ideas on how to select them?

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: *JavaScript* doesn't have selectors or layout. Selectors are a CSS concept (which has also been carried over into the DOM via `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`). Layout is an HTML and CSS concept (in this context). I suggest working through good beginner's tutorials on each of those separate subjects. It can be tricky when starting out to know what's related to what, so hopefully having some terms to search for and learn more about will help. Happy coding!

Comment: thkx for the adivce. I'll read up on the topics. I've started a beginners course I think that will be best :).

Answer (score 0):

The documentNode.getElementsByClassName returns a list of items, so while you can call .getElementsByTagName on each one, you can't call the function on the list directly.  What you need to do is something like

```
// initialize an array to hold the anchors we get, and get all menu items on the document
var firstAnchors = [], 
    menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
// iterate through the menu items and their specific anchors, adding only the first one of each menu item to our list
for(var menuItem of menuItems){
    firstAnchors.push(menuItem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]);
}
// now, our anchors should be here
console.log(firstAnchors);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parentMenus = [],
    parentMenueElems =  document.getElementById("menu-main-nav").children;
for(var parentMenueElem of parentMenueElems){

   if(!parentMenueElem){continue;}

   var parentMenue = {
       "name": parentMenueElem.firstElementChild.text,
       "anchor": parentMenueElem.firstElementChild
   };
   parentMenus.push(parentMenue);
}
console.log(parentMenus)
```

**OutPut:**

```
[
 {"name":"Portrets","anchor":element},
 {"name":"Weddings","anchor":element},
 {"name":"Wild","anchor":element},
 {"name":"Commercial Work","anchor":element},
 {"name":"About","anchor":element}
]
Example: element --> <a href="http://bertconinx.com/category/portrets/">Portrets</a>
```

Now you can perform any event on element

```
parentMenus[2].anchor.click();
```

Comment: Thkx for the help. I tjinkx its gonne work just fine.

Comment: if its fulfilling you requirements then accept the answer